# How do i dynamically add items in lazylist and resize it when the user scrolls to the end

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I'm getting data from an API which gives an array of 20 items at a time with a `next_page` attribute which gives the next set of 20 items and so on, so what i wanna do is, i want to make a lazylist of first 20 items and when the user scrolls all of the 20 items, i wanna get some callback or some way to know that lazylist haa reached its end so i could make an API call to fetch the next set of 20 items and append it on the `allItems` list and then somehow make my lazylist bigger behind the scenes, so now it have 40 items and user can scroll even further.

On `RecyclerView` it was very easy to implement that for me, i just needed to add an `onScrollStateChanged()` listener and add a simple check like:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override

        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                Log.d("-----","end");

                

            }

        }

    });
```

I wanna know how can I do the same in jetpack compose basicall

Comment: I suggest you to read about Paging with jetpack compose

Answer (score -1):

You have to make 1 master list and 1 list that came from api once api return data.
You have to insert that data to master list and send that list to recycler view adapter when it came to last position of recycler view call api and add another data to master list and so on...

Comment: Can you please actually read my post, i know how to do that in recycler view, what i was actually asking is how do i do the same with LazyList of jetpack compose.